# Prepare a string for Google Ajax Search?

Tags: python, url, google-api, google-ajax-api

I have strings such as

```
["Tabula Rasa", "façade", "DJ Tiësto"]
```

I'm accessing Google Ajax API in **Python** using the base url:

```
base = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web'
   '?v=1.0&q=%s'
```

I'm having issues using these strings plain and noticed I have to transform certain characters,

```
eg. "Tabula Rasa" -->  "Tabula%20Rasa"
```

But I have a huge list of these strings and I do not know of a way I can automatically prepare these string for the URL query.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is urllib.quote():

```
>>> urllib.quote("Tabula Rasa")
'Tabula%20Rasa'
```

The non-ASCII strings may need to be recoded into the encoding expected by the Google AJAX API, if you don't have them in the same encoding already.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
How would I go on about unicode characters? Or characters extracted from an html page?

Comment: If you have unicode, you first need to encode it into the encoding expected by the Google AJAX API (presumably UTF-8, so `data.encode('utf-8')`.) If you have characters extracted from a HTML page, I would hope you have them in a unicode string -- but if you have them as a bytestring, decode them using the encoding used by the webpage. Then you encode into the right encoding like any other unicode object.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. Indeed very helpful! :) I'll look into this.